# Inside a CSS table container, how can I move a single table-cell into the next row by touching only its CSS?

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML:

```
<div class='container'>
  <div class='first'>test</div>
  <div class='second'>test</div>
</div>
```

accompied by the following CSS:

```
.container {
  display: table;
  width: 90%;
  background: yellow;
}

.first {
  display: table-cell;
  background: red;
}

.second {
  display: table-cell;
  background: blue;
}
```

(Also: http://codepen.io/zssz/pen/GodBqQ)

How can I achieve that the second/blue div sits right below the first/red div, by **ONLY** changing the CSS of `.second`?

Thank you

(I have no control over the container CSS in this situation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

**CSS**

```
.second {
  display: table-row;
  background: blue;
}
```

**[DEMO HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/luispa/ofaf9g4h/4/)**

Comment: Thank you! that did it indeed. Is it valid / semantically correct to declare content as a row or is it more of a hack? (for example the padding in my codepen isn't respected anymore, see http://codepen.io/zssz/pen/EPLejw)

Comment: @user511287 Both! It´s valid semantically (HTML5) and is a hack :)